# Synthetic Control with Weights Summing to more than 1

Tags: r, controls, synthetic

I am using the Synth package in R to run synthetic control (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Synth/Synth.pdf).
I would like to obtain weights, which are not restricted to sum to 1.
Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[augsynth](https://github.com/ebenmichael/augsynth) is probably your best bet!

Here is an example that fits the donors and has negative weights, from this [vignette](https://github.com/ebenmichael/augsynth/blob/master/vignettes/singlesynth-vignette.md).

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(augsynth)
data(kansas)
kansas %>% 
  select(year, qtr, year_qtr, state, treated, gdp, lngdpcapita) %>% 
  filter(state == "Kansas" & year_qtr >= 2012 & year_qtr < 2013)
syn <- augsynth(lngdpcapita ~ treated, fips, year_qtr, kansas,
                progfunc = "Ridge", scm = T)
print(syn$weights)
```

In the output you'll see that some of the weights are negative:

```
> print(syn$weights)
            [,1]
1  -0.0017595899
2   0.0710153931
4  -0.0002083812
```

I am not an author of or contributor to augsynth.

Comment: affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball I am not an author of or contributor to augsynth

Comment: Ok I've done that! :) Is there a policy that every time you link to a package you didn't make you should say that you were _not_ the maker of the package?